# How to ensure the same cloud function does not run at the same time?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I currently have a situation where I am using the `compose` function to merge multiple text files in a Cloud Storage bucket. This will be a cloud function that is triggered by new files hitting the bucket. Once the files are merged, the old ones will be deleted.

That being said, there will be situations where files will hit the bucket simultaneously. How do I make sure there won't be a case of duplication?

For example:

1. Bucket contains: File1
2. File 2 hits the bucket
3. Cloud function runs and merges the two files.
4. File 3 hits the bucket while this happens and triggers the cloud function as well which merges File1,File2,File3.
5. new files (file4 & file 5) are created due to step 3 and 4. File1,2,3 are deleted.

I'm just wondering if this will happen? What can I do to prevent this from happening? Ideally the function should run when a new file hits the bucket. If a second file hits the bucket, it should be in the queue, and only runs after the first run has completed.

Appreciate any help that you can offer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To achieve your use case, you have to prevent multiple function execution. For that, you can set the [max instance to 1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances).

*Note: only one event can be processed by a Cloud Functions instance (in v1)*

But, if you have 2 events in the same time, one will be processed by the Cloud Functions, the second one will get a 429 errors code and won't be processed. To avoid that situation, you can [activate the retry feature](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries)

---

Be careful, you have no guarantee in the processing order. If it's a requirement, a much more complex design must be set up.

Comment: would you agree that without having a proper rule set up, possible duplication might occur?

Comment: Most of the time, duplication shouldn't occur, but it's possible. Your system must be resilient of that rare use case.